# Could an amr audio file bytes contains a `#` character?

Tags: sockets, audio, codec, multimedia, amr

I'm developing a socket communicate routine, and the messages delimiter is a single `#` character.

And the data sending may contain `.amr` audio files. I want to confirm whether the content of the file might contains the `#` delimiter character, which may cause unexpected interrupt.

Anyone familiar with media codec can answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a binary file format every possible byte value may be present. Since a '#' is just a byte with value 0x23 it may be present in the file.